# How to handle touch or press down events in Android?

Tags: java, android

Alright so i have 4 image views..

How can i control what happens when they are pressed down and up

So say like:

one of the images is press down a textview gets changed to 1 but when they let go of that one the text will change back to 0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and have it listen for `TouchEvents` on your `Views`.

For Example:

```
MyTouchListener l = new MyTouchListener();
view.setOnTouchListener(l);
```

Here is an example of what `MyTouchListener` could look like:

```
class MyOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // touch down code
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // touch move code
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // touch up code
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: implements, with an 'S'