# How to play audio only while button is held down?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple app: there is one button in the middle which a child would press. As long as that button is held down it would play a certain MP3.

At the moment, I tried with `onClick`, but, that plays only when the button is released.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643146/how-to-handle-touch-or-press-down-events-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an [`onClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) which exposes nothing more then an interface for press and release, you would need to use an [`onTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) - which exposes all touch events of a view.

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch ( event.getAction() ) {

            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // start playing
                return true;

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // stop playing
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Using the boolean "playing" you can create a thread/loop elsewhere to check if still playing and keep audio going.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playing = true;
        } else {
            playing = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the OnFocusChangeListener

```
 Button.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when Button loses focus, i.e. stop music
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a button is a view component you can use [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) event listener with ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS & ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Here is an example:

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS){

            // Start Video
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE) { 
            // End Video

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer here.How should I fit this into my programming? I have this code right now that only plays the sound when button is released:

Comment: I mean in a answer lower down that is now a answer.

Comment: @user7323126, Please share your activity code and I will write you where to add this code. :)

Comment: it is in the second "answer" higher up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void start_recording(View view){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```