# Android Things onTouch doesnt release GPIO

Tags: java, android, android-things

I am using **Android Things v1** and trying to use an on-screen `Button` to activate a motor as long as the `button` is pressed (**tap & long press**).

The problem I have is once the `button` is pressed the motor will not stop. I would like it to stop once the `button` is released.

Here is the `button` code:

```
    mtrbtnGD.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            try {
                mtrGpio = manager.openGpio("BCM24");
                mtrGpio.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_NONE);
                mtrGpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
                mtrGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
                mtrGpio.setValue(true);
                Log.i(TAG, "Motor started");

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access GPIO", e);
            }
           return true;
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

Here is the new code from Sam's reply:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Gpio mtrGpio;
private GestureDetector mtrbtnGD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mtrbtnGD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mtrbtn);
    Button closebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
    Button stopmtrbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopmtrbtn);

    final PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
    List<String> portList = manager.getGpioList();
    if (portList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No GPIO port available on this device.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of available ports: " + portList);
    }

    mtrbtnGD.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            try {

                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // PRESSED
                        mtrGpio = manager.openGpio("BCM24");
                        mtrGpio.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_NONE);
                        mtrGpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
                        mtrGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
                        mtrGpio.setValue(true);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Motor started");
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // RELEASED
                        mtrGpio.close();

                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                }



            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access GPIO", e);
            }
           return true;
        }
    });
```

The motor still doesn't stop when I release the on-screen button.

Comment: Take a look at this, you need to add events for `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643146/how-to-handle-touch-or-press-down-events-in-android

Comment: you removed the key part of the answer, which is mtrGpio.value = false inside ACTION_UP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close()` closes your connection to the GPIO peripheral, it does not change the value of that connection before closing it. You need to use `setValue(false);` as so:

```
               switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // PRESSED
                        mtrGpio = manager.openGpio("BCM24");
                        mtrGpio.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_NONE);
                        mtrGpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
                        mtrGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
                        mtrGpio.setValue(true);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Motor started");
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // RELEASED
                        mtrGpio.setValue(false); // ADD THIS
                        mtrGpio.close();

                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                }
```

Ideally, if you expect the motor to be turned on and off a lot, you should keep the connection open.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Gpio mtrGpio;
private GestureDetector mtrbtnGD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mtrbtnGD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mtrbtn);
    try {
      PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
      mtrGpio = manager.openGpio("BCM24");
      mtrGpio.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_NONE);
      mtrGpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
      mtrGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("cannot open gpio", e);
    }

    mtrbtnGD.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            try {
               switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // PRESSED
                        mtrGpio.setValue(true);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Motor started");
                        return true; 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // RELEASED
                        mtrGpio.setValue(false);
                        return true; 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access GPIO", e);
            }
           return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   try {
      mtrGpio.close();
   } catch (IOException ignore) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Unable to close GPIO", ignore);
   }
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside `onTouch` method and Check `event.getAction()` :

```
switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for replying. I have update the post to show the code that you have suggested but I'm guessing that I've done something wrong since the motor doesn't stop when I take my finger off the on screen button.

Comment: Another issue is that you are not turning off the value of the GPIO even though you close it. Closing the GPIO does not change its value. You need to explicitly set `mtrGpio.setValue(false);` before closing.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I missed that.